# My Mean Value Function is Not Working Properly (C++)

Tags: c++

Hey there I have an array which is described above. I want to find the mean of it. I am not a newbie to programming but somehow this function is not working properly. I want to know what I am missing. The result of the function must be 49.75 but it shows as 50. Here is my array and my function:

```
const int grades[] = { 96, 0, 77, 82, 87, 8, 40, 20, 80, 43, 91, 18, 26, 15, 17, 83, 58, 55, 14, 85 };

const int SIZE = sizeof(grades) / sizeof(grades[0]);
cout << "mean is: " << setw(5) << setprecision(2) << mean(grades, SIZE) << endl;




double mean(const int grades[], int SIZE)

{

double sumElements = grades[0];
for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    sumElements += grades[i];

}
return sumElements / SIZE;
}
```

Comment: works fine for gcc 9.3 https://godbolt.org/z/TZ-N3S It may has something to do with setw and setprecision

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Just for paranoias sake, consider tested for SIZE == 0 to avoid zero division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any other settings, [`std::setprecision(2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) means "*round value so that two significant digits are printed*". First two significant digits are tens and integers, so it gets rounded to nearest integer.

You can combine your output line with [`std::fixed()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) call to make it actually print two digits after decimal point.

```
std::cout << "mean is: " << std::setw(5) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << mean(grades, SIZE) << std::endl;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: Yes that was the case. Thank you so much for your help.